# CodeIgniter video files not uploading on web server

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, codeigniter, video, mime-types

I have created a codeigniter application with a file upload feature. This is loaded as my Facebook app in a Canvas page. I have set my allowed types as png,jpg, mp4.

When tested on localhost this works fine and uploads well.

However, when uploaded on my server and installed as my canvas app, when I access my page via apps.facebook.com/myapp, the images are uploaded fine, BUT, when I try to upload a mp4 file, thatwas successfully uploaded on localhost version, it returns the upload error "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.".

But I have set it as an allowed type.

I tried uploading via the canvas url (www.myapps.com/apps) rather than the canvas page (apps.facebook.com/myapp), but it gives the same problem, it says the type is not allowed.

I thought it might be server not configured so I add `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` to the server's and app folder's .htaccess.

Also I made sure that mp4 is added in the mime.php in my codeigniter app.

Just not sure what to do again. It keeps saying it's not allowed, but it is.

Any help would be great. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the both mime types in the list in the config folder for codeigniter. Like this.

```
'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'application/octet-stream')
```

Comment: in mimes.php ?Currently in application/config/mimes.php I have `'mp4'=> 'video/mp4'`

Comment: yes change it to look like my answer and see if that will work for you.